# Customer relationship systems for shops and smartphones

Tags: crm

I was wondering what customer relationship management software exists for Android.

I am looking for a software that allows store managers to keep track of what customers have said to them (even sharing and importing chats from customers, from messaging apps, or from jotted down conversations in Google keep, to the software system). The system should also interface with what they have bought (importing from smart shopping list or product reader machines that record customer intubation transmitted via card and fidelity card, for instance).

Ideally, the system could use something like FireBase or Google Drive as a backend server, if data need be shared between managers/staff members. Thanks.

What such software systems are available on Android?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. In general, such Android systems will also have a backend server. This is to enable mutiple staff/managers to access same data. If this is what you want, please rephrase your question. I can then give an answer.

Comment: I have updated my post. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi. To start with, did you try out any of the solutions here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/86953/software-system-along-the-lines-of-customer-relationship-management-software-for/86954#86954 . If on a google drive, you have to worry about data syncronisation/integrity when mutli-user updates occur.