# Software system along the lines of customer relationship management software for schools, teachers, children, and parents

Tags: android, crm, android-app

I am looking for a software system for smartphones that would keep track of children, for people that have to keep track of many children, and, later, when they think about them, review, think about, or write down things about them.

This could be used equally by preschool or maternity teachers or elementary, middle school, or high school teachers, or parents alike.

How would you design such a system.

These people have a lot to do.

Perhaps, a system could really help.

Because, it could allow them to keep track of what they have done at home after each day.

They have very busy lives.

They are to be admired.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you take care of all the security issues associated with children, there are a couple of CRMs I'd recommend for this:

- [Monica](https://github.com/monicahq/monica)
- [SuiteCRM](https://suitecrm.com/)

Both are open-source. If configured properly they can do most of what you need on a smartphone via Android Client or Web Browser i.e. notes, tracking, reviews etc.

The backend will run on a server (Linux/Windows/MacOS), and hence is multi-user.

You can look at these for ideas on how to build.

There are also such systems built specifically for schools.

Comment: Thank you. What are some examples of such systems built specifically for schools? Thanks.

Comment: An example is https://gibbonedu.org/. I have also done related stuff in past using drupal and some of its modules.

Comment: Hi. Did you try them out?